# Is there a way to match two different data frames for multiple columns

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want to make a link between columns by the condition. I have two data frames as follows:

```html
df1<-read.table(text=" gol
4
7
6
9
",header=TRUE)
```

and the second df is :

```html
df2<-read.table(text=" cost1 cost2 cost3 cost4
7 9 5 13
3 12 4 14
9 13 3 11
5 6 2 13
4 3 5 12
8 16 6 9
9 11 2 9
6 14 11 12
5 10 14 6
2 9 4 12

",header=TRUE)
```

The condition is, for example, in df2, cost1,  if the value is greater or equal to **4** in df1, it gets "y" else it gets "n". in Cost 2 if the value greater or equal to 7 in df1, it gets "y" else it gets "n" and so on. Please assume I have more than four columns.

The outcome would be as follows:

```html
output<-read.table(text=" cost1 cost2 cost3 cost4 out1 out2 out3 out4
7 9 5 13 y y n y
                   3 12 4 14 n y n y
                   9 13 3 11 y y n y
                   5 6 2 13 y n n y
                   4 3 5 12 y n n y
                   8 16 6 9 y y y y
                   9 11 2 9 y y n y
                   6 14 11 12 y y y y
                   5 10 14 6 y y y n
                   2 9 4 12 n y n y
                   ",header=TRUE)
```

I just now I need to do it using ifelse, but  I struggled to do it for this example. Your help very miuch appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably better and more elegant solution that I haven't think yet, but using a `for` loop with an `ifelse` function, you can do something like that:

```r
dfx <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=ncol(df2),nrow = nrow(df2)))
for(i in 1:ncol(df2))
{
  dfx[,i] <- ifelse(df2[,i] >= df1[i,1],"y","n")
  colnames(dfx)[i] <- paste0("out",i)
}
out <- cbind(df2,dfx)
```

And you get the following output:

```r
> out
   cost1 cost2 cost3 cost4 out1 out2 out3 out4
1      7     9     5    13    y    y    n    y
2      3    12     4    14    n    y    n    y
3      9    13     3    11    y    y    n    y
4      5     6     2    13    y    n    n    y
5      4     3     5    12    y    n    n    y
6      8    16     6     9    y    y    y    y
7      9    11     2     9    y    y    n    y
8      6    14    11    12    y    y    y    y
9      5    10    14     6    y    y    y    n
10     2     9     4    12    n    y    n    y
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution without using `for-loop`:

```
r <- setNames(data.frame(as.matrix(df2)>=outer(rep(1,nrow(df2)),df1$gol)),
              paste0("out",seq(ncol(df2))))
r[r==T] <- "y"
r[r==F] <- "n"
res <- cbind(df2,r)
```

which gives:

```
> res
   cost1 cost2 cost3 cost4 out1 out2 out3 out4
1      7     9     5    13    y    y    n    y
2      3    12     4    14    n    y    n    y
3      9    13     3    11    y    y    n    y
4      5     6     2    13    y    n    n    y
5      4     3     5    12    y    n    n    y
6      8    16     6     9    y    y    y    y
7      9    11     2     9    y    y    n    y
8      6    14    11    12    y    y    y    y
9      5    10    14     6    y    y    y    n
10     2     9     4    12    n    y    n    y
```